# Azure - App Service Docker Compose - is working_directory supported?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node app that I'm running in Azure App Service however in my docker-compose file the option for `working_dir` doesn't seem to actually do anything. I've tested locally with the same image I have pushed to the registry and it works, just not on Azure.

I just want to check is it actually supported?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provide in the question shows you the support and not support options, the option `working_dir` is not in both. But the Note also tells it:

> Any other options not explicitly called out are ignored in Public
> Preview.

So in fact, the option `working_dir` is ignored. Instead, I recommend you use the `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile.